# Are (new) parts purchased from or replaced by the original manufacturer subject to protections under lemon laws as a new product?

Tags: united-states, california, consumer-protection, lemon-law, ucc

Say, you purchase a passenger vehicle with some of the original warranty given by the manufacturer remaining. Knowing the typical issues with the vehicle, you decide to buy some spare parts — each new, from the manufacturer as OEM.

Are they, each on their own, protected under "lemon laws" in the U.S. or in any states? Are they considered "goods" under U.C.C. or "consumer goods" under state lemon laws?

I'm primarily interested in California and the Song-Beverly Consumer Warranty Act, but any other U.S. states' decisions or statutes would be interesting to me, too; and, of course, any other country’s consumer laws could provide insightful comparisons.